# Decompose $V \otimes V$ as a direct sum of irreducible representations.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V$ be an irreducible representation of $A_{4}$ of dimension $3$ over a
splitting field $F$ of $A_{4}$ of characteristic $\neq 2,3$. How to decompose $V \otimes V$ as a direct sum of irreducible representations?

Could you please give me any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with inner products of characters? They would do it all over $\Bbb{C}$ and quite a bit survives over other fields. I would definitely start with that decomposition, and see how the land lies in other characteristics. You do have the necessarily roots of unity in $F$ anyway.

Comment: "Tensor squares" can be decomposed into a symmetric and and antisymmetric part and there is a rule for the dimension of these parts for the antisymmetric part its $n(n-1)/2$. So it should be $3$ in your case and then $6$ for the symmetric part. Maybe that helps?